# GWT fire events

Tags: java, gwt

I'm using GWT 2.4 by using the MVP pattern

I have this situation:
In one presenter (let's call it a TreePresenter since it shows a tree) i have the following code:

```
display.getSelectedItem().addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<TreeItem>() {

        @Override
        public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<TreeItem> event) {
            ....
            evtBus.fireEvent(new SelectCategoryEvent(item.getText()));
            .....
        }
    });
```

And in my AppController class I have this situation:

```
        eventBus.addHandler(SelectCategoryEvent.TYPE, new SelectCategoryEventHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectCategory(SelectCategoryEvent event) {
            saveHistoryEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

When i select one itm in the three the event is correctly fired by the instruction

```
evtBus.fireEvent(new SelectCategoryEvent(item.getText()));
```

But in my AppController the event is not propagated and I can't handle it in the code

```
        eventBus.addHandler(SelectCategoryEvent.TYPE, new SelectCategoryEventHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectCategory(SelectCategoryEvent event) {
            saveHistoryEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

Can anybody tell me the reason?

Thank
Angelo

I'll give you some detail; I built a class for my own history management; I built this class:

```
public class GwtHistoryEventsMgr {


private Map<String, List<GwtEvent>> tknEvts;
private HandlerManager eventBus;
public GwtHistoryEventsMgr(HandlerManager evtBus){

    tknEvts = new HashMap<String, List<GwtEvent>>();
    this.eventBus = evtBus;

}

private void saveHistoryEvent( GwtEvent event ){

    List<GwtEvent> eventi = null;
    if( tknEvts.containsKey(History.getToken()) ){

        eventi = tknEvts.get(History.getToken());
    }else{

        eventi = new ArrayList<GwtEvent>();
    }
    eventi.add(event);
    tknEvts.put(History.getToken(), eventi);
}
public void addEvtHandlers(){

    //Aggiungo gli handler 
    eventBus.addHandler(CustomEvent.TYPE, new CustomEventHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onEvent(CustomEvent event) {

            saveHistoryEvent(event);
        }
    });

}
public List<GwtEvent> getTokenTransWidgetEvents(String token){

    if( tknEvts.containsKey(token) ){

        return tknEvts.remove(token);
    }else{

        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Then in my AppController constructor I wrote this code:

```
public AppController(HandlerManager eventBus, StandardDispatchAsync dispatcher){
    super(null);
    this.eventBus = eventBus;
    this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    //Gestione history
    histMgr = new GwtHistoryEventsMgr(eventBus);
    histMgr.addEvtHandlers();
}
```

This means that I should be pretty sure that the AppController registers itself to the events I want (note: I strongly reduced the code...but all the code is in the way I wrote)

Then, since I use client-side reflection, I did, where I use the client side reflection, this code (after that all widgets have been initialized):

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private void generateHistoricalEvents(){

    List<GwtEvent> eventi = hisMgr.getTokenTransWidgetEvents(History.getToken());
    //Ci sono eventi....vuol dire back del browser cliccato
    if( eventi != null ){

        for (GwtEvent gwtEvent : eventi) {

            this.eventBus.fireEvent(gwtEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

According to me it's all OK; may you tell me where the problem is?

Thank you
Angelo

Comment: You're sure that both event busses are one and the same object? Sounds trivial I know but I've seen this one more than once if no DI is used or DI was configured wrongly...

Comment: Hi; yes I'm sure about it; I checked more then once by debugging code....and I'm also sure that I never delete events from the event bus

Comment: Ok. From the code you provided it's pretty hard to see what might go wrong. If you know that the event is successfully passed to the event bus could you then please post your `AppController`? Might be that you register the handler after the event has already been processed. Just a wild guess...

Comment: @z00bs I just noticed that there is another presenter who processes the events (but it doesn't remove it from the bus); sadly the app controller is huge (I got it from other developers) but I'm pretty sure that the flow is the following one: 1) the treepresenter generates an event 2) a controller consumers this event 3) the appcontroller is listening to this event; as far as I know till events on the event bus should remain till i don't remove them (by doing removeHandler) am I wrong?

Comment: That's normally the case yes. Did you verify that the `AppController` registers itself in time?

Comment: @z00bs Please see the answer below....here I can't paste code properly

Comment: @z00bs sorry...I added some updates to the original question; I tried to give you as much information as possible

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37956/discussion-between-angelo-immediata-and-z00bs)

Comment: @z00bs: i did some mistake; now...by being carefully in where to put the registration of my AppController it works properly; thank you

Comment: NP, glad you could fix it.